# Al hacer click en checkbox agregar estilos a su contenedor padre css / jquery

Tags: html, jquery, css

Como podria hacer que al dar click sobre una de las tarjetas se aplique los mismos estilos que tiene en hover (border y box-shadow)? es como si fuese el active. Cuando se da click en la tarjeta, en si se esta dando click al label que ocupa todo el ancho y alto de su padre, el input de tipo checkbox no tiene ancho para que no sea visible porque estoy haciendo que el circulo que se muestra tenga estilos especificos que me han pedido...
Adjunto el codigo de estructura y estilos de lo que mas o menos tengo hasta el momento

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.wrapper-card {
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  background: pink;
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 20px;
}

.wrapper-card:hover {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 21px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}

.select-product-area {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

label {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
}

input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}

input:checked~.checkmark {
  border-color: blue;
}

input:checked~.checkmark:after {
  display: block;
}

.checkmark {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: 1.87px solid #000;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  top: 18px;
}

.checkmark::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  left: 7px;
  top: 3px;
  width: 7px;
  height: 12px;
  border: solid blue;
  border-width: 0 1.87px 1.97px 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper-card">
    <div class="select-product-area">
      <label class="selected-product" for="tablet-2015">
              <input type="checkbox" id="tablet-2015" name="tablet-2015" data-name-display="tablet-2015" />
              <span class="checkmark"></span>
          </label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper-card">
    <div class="select-product-area">
      <label class="selected-product" for="desktop-2020">
              <input type="checkbox" id="desktop-2020" name="desktop-2020" data-name-display="desktop-2020" />
              <span class="checkmark"></span>
          </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

creo que esto es lo que necesitas un poco de JQuery para que cada vez que se de clic en los checkbox verifique si fuer checked o no y así pueda agregar una clase con los estilos que tiene el hover.

```js
$("#tablet-2015, #desktop-2020").change(function(){
  if( $(this).is(':checked') ){
      $(this).parent().parent().parent().addClass('wrapper-card-active');
  }else{
      $(this).parent().parent().parent().removeClass('wrapper-card-active');
  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.wrapper-card {
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  background: pink;
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 20px;
}

.wrapper-card:hover {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 21px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}

.wrapper-card-active {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 21px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}

.select-product-area {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

label {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
}

input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}

input:checked~.checkmark {
  border-color: blue;
}

input:checked~.checkmark:after {
  display: block;
}

.checkmark {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: 1.87px solid #000;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  top: 18px;
}

.checkmark::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  left: 7px;
  top: 3px;
  width: 7px;
  height: 12px;
  border: solid blue;
  border-width: 0 1.87px 1.97px 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper-card">
    <div class="select-product-area">
      <label class="selected-product" for="tablet-2015">
              <input type="checkbox" id="tablet-2015" name="tablet-2015" data-name-display="tablet-2015" />
              <span class="checkmark"></span>
          </label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper-card">
    <div class="select-product-area">
      <label class="selected-product" for="desktop-2020">
              <input type="checkbox" id="desktop-2020" name="desktop-2020" data-name-display="desktop-2020" />
              <span class="checkmark"></span>
          </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

También puedes usar el método `.toggleClass()` hace lo mismo que si usaras `.addClass()` y `.removeClass()` pero de manera más resumida.

Te quedaría algo tal que así:

```
$("#tablet-2015, #desktop-2020").change(function(){
      $(this).parent().parent().parent().toggleClass('wrapper-card-active');
});
```